# Synonym für anregen, motivieren, führen zu

Tags: synonym

Im konkreten Fall geht es um einen Fragebogen, der anonym ausgefüllt und ausgewertet wird und so besonders ehrliche Antworten … soll. Hier sind mir Wörter wie

- anregen
- motivieren
- führen zu

eingefallen, aber keines von denen drückt genau das aus, was ich sagen möchte – eben eine Kombination aus diesen Dingen, so dass die Leute beim Ausfüllen des Fragebogens besonders ehrliche Antworten geben.

http://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/anregen.php macht noch Vorschläge wie

- aktivieren
- nahe legen
- anbieten

u. v. m., ich bin aber mit keinem so recht glücklich.

Hat jemand einen guten Vorschlag, oder kann ich das Gewünschte nur anders, ggf. mit zwei verschiedenen Verben, ausdrücken?

Comment: Suchst du ein Wort, dass in den Teilsatz "besonders ehrliche Antworten ... soll" passt (sprich auf den Fragebogen referenziert), oder suchst du ein Wort, dass das ganze eher aus der Betrachtungsweise desjenigen, der den Fragebogen ausfüllt, beschreibt? Also "Der Fragenbogen, der besonders ehrlichen Antworten hervorbringen soll" oder "Der Befragte, der durch Anonymität zur Ehrlichkeit animiert wird"?

Comment: Ich habe gerade keine Zeit, eine Antwort auszuarbeiten, deswegen werfe ich einfach ein paar Worte in den Raum, an denen sich jeder bedienen kann, der möchte: *bestärken, begünstigen, bewirken, stimulieren, provozieren, animieren.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hier meine Vorschläge.

> …, und so … Antworten begünstigen/befördern/zutage bringen soll.

(Nicht-Anonymität ist ja mehr als alles andere eine Hemmschwelle)

> …, und so zu besonders ehrlichen Antworten animieren soll.
>
> …, und so die Teilnehmer zu … Antworten ermutigen/ermuntern/einladen soll.

**Animieren** ist mein Favorit.

Comment: "begünstigen" und "zu ... animieren" finde ich beide sehr gut, vielen Dank!